# Bash string replace function similar to Javascript String.prototype.replace()

Tags: javascript, bash, sed, sh

In JS, I can use a function [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) when replacing a submatch in a regular expression. For example:

```
var x = 'a1b2c3'.replace(/(\d+)/g, (num) => {
    return num*num+1
})
console.log(x)
// 'a2b5c10'
```

I've tried using `sed` but it seems that invoking an operator `$(())` inside of the replacement is not possible.

```
$ echo "a1b2c3" | sed 's/\([^0-9]*\)\([0-9]\)\([^0-9]*\)/\1$((\2*\2+1))\3/g'
# Output: a$((1*1+1))b$((2*2+1))c$((3*3+1))
```

Is there a similar tool or function in `bash` that has the functionality similar to JS's `String.replace()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bash` shell does support a native regex operator which you can enable with the `~` flag. All you need to do is define a regex, take the captured groups and replace them with the modified values

```
str='a1b2c3'
re='^.*([0-9]+).*([0-9]+).*([0-9]+).*$'
if [[ $str =~ $re ]]; then
    for match in "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"; do
        final="${str/$match/$((match*match+1))}"
    done
fi
printf '%s\n' "$final"
```

The `[[ $str =~ $re ]]` does the regex match and updates the captured group array `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}`. So for each of the element in the order of their appearance, we do the string substitution operator `${str/old/new}`. The replacement value in your case is the number multiplied with itself and added by 1.

Add more capturing groups to the regex `.*([0-9]+)` for subsequent matches.

---

If not for a pure `bash` solution above, using an external utility like `perl`, one could do it as

```
perl -pe 's/\d+/$&*$&+1/ge' <<<"$str"
```

The `$&` refers to the captured digit in the string and the `e` flag allows do arithmetic operations over the captured groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this in gawk using `match()` and `substr()`.

```
echo "a1b2c3" | awk '{
    head = ""
    tail = $0

    while (match(tail, /[0-9]+/)) {
        num = substr(tail, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        num = num * num + 1
        head = head substr(tail, 1, RSTART-1) num
        tail = substr(tail, RSTART + RLENGTH)
    }

    print head tail
}'
```

Output

```
a2b5c10
```